# Angular2 - module function returning 'undefined'

Tags: angular

In my Angular2 app, I am trying to import Phoenix channels using the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-phoenix-channels. I am having an issue where trying to access certain attributes of the imported script returns an 'undefined' error.

First off, this is all taking place in `person.service.ts`. The module doesn't have a typescript definition file, so it is imported like so:

```
import * as angular2PhoenixChannels from 'angular2-phoenix-channels';
var PhoenixChannels = angular2PhoenixChannels;
```

If I run a `console.log` in the following context (log is toward the bottom in getPerson()):

```
@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
    private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/';
    private phoenixChannels = PhoenixChannels;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        console.log('Service ready...');
    }

      getPeople(): Promise<Person[]> {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http
          .get(this.apiUrl + 'people', options)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json().data as Person[])
      }

      getPerson(id: number): Promise<Person> {
          console.log(this.phoenixChannels.default.prototype.channel)
          return this.getPeople()
            .then(people => people.find(person => person.id === id));
      }
}
```

This logs:

```
function channel(topic) {
  return new PhoenixChannel(this.socket, topic);
}
```

which looks good to me.  However, if I try to pass an argument to the `channel()` function like so:

```
console.log(this.phoenixChannels.default.prototype.channel("testing"))
```

This returns the error

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined
```

Why has this object suddenly become undefined?

Comment: How are you calling the `channel` function?

Comment: Shouldn't you inject the `PhoenixChannels` in your `PersonService` constructor?